# When converting from infix to postfix, how do you specify between a uniary and a binary +/-

Tags: infix-notation, unary-operator, postfix-notation, binary-operators

Under this grammar:

```
^ + -  *  /  <  >  =  <= >=  and  or  not
```

I'm using a function (shunting-yard algorithm) to convert from infix to postfix and it works! Except it doesn't include the unary - meaning negate and the unary + which doesn't really do much of anything.

Once converted to post fix, a unary + will be a p and a unary - with be a m. For example:

```
3 + 3     ->     3 3 +
+3 + 3    ->     3 p 3 +
-(3-3)    ->     3 3 - m
```

So if I am reading an infix expression, how do I specify between a unary and binary plus and minus?

Comment: "p" for positive and "m" for negative? OK. Well, the unary + or - are always in front of a number, so if you find one just after a number, you can be sure that it's a binary one. But now I'm writing this, that sounds too simple. I'll look up the shunting-yard algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the following rule would apply.

The first `+` or `-` following a non-operator is a binary operator. Subsequent occurrences (or an occurrence at the start of an expression) are unary.

So, in your (and a couple of extra) examples:

```
3 + 3             --> 3 binary+ 3
+ 3 + 3           --> unary+ 3 binary+ 3
- ( 3 - 3)        --> unary- ( 3 binary- 3)
-9--4             --> unary- 9 binary- unary- 4
```